# graph algorithm to detect even cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have an undirected graph. One edge in that graph is special. I want to find all other edges that are part of a even cycle containing the first edge.

I don't need to enumerate all the cycles, that would be inherently NP I think. I just need to know, for each each edge, whether it satisfies the conditions above.

A brute force search works of course but is too slow, and I'm struggling to come up with anything better. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is insufficient information here to provide an answer of the quality you are seeking. How far ahead of time do you know which edge is special? Are you allowed to preprocess the data? How much do you touch the data beforehand (e.g. load it), and can you modify how you preprocess the data?

Comment: Furthermore, you might possibly need to look at all the cycles **if** you cannot abuse preprocessing, though I can't think of a proof of that assertion one way or another.

Comment: @ninjagecko The graph represents a chemical structure, i.e. the vertices are atoms and the edges are chemical bonds between those atoms. The chemical structure is being continuously edited by the user and this algorithm is expected to run in real time as the user performs edits. We use a simple adjacency list structure for the graph, although we do maintain a few other structures as well (for instance we know at all times whether an edge is part of a cycle or not). If I understand you right, preprocessing is not an option, since the graph (and the special edge) are always changing.

Comment: "although we do maintain a few other structures as well (for instance we know at all times whether an edge is part of a cycle or not)" -- perhaps this structure be modified to keep track of whether it's part of an even cycle? What kind of structure is it? (Preprocessing should be doable since the user loads the chemical from a file or it's generated somehow which is an O(N) operation, but may not be necessary.)

Comment: Are the cycles restricted to simple cycles?  Would two triangles connected by an edge between their tips (kind of an hourglass shape) count as a length 8 cycle, with the middle edge being used twice?

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki A cycle that uses the same edge or vertex twice doesn't count.

Comment: Interesting algorithmic challenge. Have my own idea, but it require coding and testing. If you base your solution on DFS and handle edge cases right (using DP), you should be able to solve this in (n+m)Logn time. which should be good enough for real time.

Comment: @Icfseth DP is dynamic programming? It's been a long time since I looked at that. Could you give me an indication of what you have in mind?

Comment: @john: Isn't this graph quite sparse as you only have at most 4 or so atoms bonded to any given atom?

Comment: @JPvdMerwe Typically you are talking about carbon atoms, so two, three or four would be the typical number of adjacent carbon atoms. But that's quite enough to get an exponential explosion in the number of cycles.

Comment: @john: what order is the number of atoms you are dealing with?

Comment: @JPvdMerwe The typical case is no problem, it's when the user inputs one of the pathological cases that we get problems. A typical problem case is the C60 molecule, buckminsterfullerene, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene. There are worse cases than that however.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have an answer (I must credit my colleague with the idea). Essentially his idea is to do a flood fill algorithm through the space of even cycles. This works because if you have a large even cycle formed by merging two smaller cycles then the smaller cycles must have been both even or both odd. Similarly merging an odd and even cycle always forms a larger odd cycle.

This is a practical option only because I can imagine pathological cases consisting of alternating even and odd cycles. In this case we would never find two adjacent even cycles and so the algorithm would be slow. But I'm confident that such cases don't arise in real chemistry. At least in chemistry as it's currently known, 30 years ago we'd never heard of fullerenes.

Answer (score -1):

If your graph has a small node degree, you might consider using a different graph representation:

Let three atoms `u,v,w` and two chemical bonds `e=(u,v)` and `k=(v,w)`. A typical way of representing such data is to store `u,v,w` as nodes and `e,k` as edges in a graph.

However, one may represent `e` and `k` as nodes in the graph, having edges like `f=(e,k)` where `f` represents a 2-step link from `u` to `w`, `f=(e,k)` or `f=(u,v,w)`. Running any algorithm to find cycles on such a graph will return all even cycles on the original graph.

Of course, this is efficient only if the original graph has a small node degree. When a user performs an edit, you can easily edit accordingly the alternative representation.